# Set dropdown button width to same as dropdown item width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a dropdown div and its button width is different from that of its dropdown items. I want the button and the dropdown items to have the same width.

```
<div class="dropdown col">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a form</button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu col-xs-12">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">word</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">word</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Very long word</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The width of `Very long word` item is the same as that of `word` items, only the button that has a different width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do that would be to wrap the button and the dropdown menu to a new div and set your desired width in it (I've set a width of 200px for the example), then just making its children (button + dropdown menu) inherit their parent's div width (`width: inherit !important;`) like so :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="dropdown col">
    <div style="width: 200px;">
        <button style="width: inherit !important;" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Choose a form</button>
        <ul style="width: inherit !important;" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-center">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">word</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">word</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Very long word</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure from your tags if you're looking for a bootsrap specific answer, but one option would be to set the parent, `.dropown`container to `display: flex` with `flex-direction:column`, expanding the child items on the flex parents primary axis.

```
.dropdown {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It sets the button width to be 100% of the column.